# How to specify a column range according to a formula in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

I'm trying to calculate a formula based on a column of data, and I want to choose the column based on a number in an adjacent cell. Here's a simplified example of what I want to do:

[image]

Say I was trying to find the SUM of each column based on the group number in Column A. What formula would I type into Cell B2 to specify I want to look at the column indicated in Cell A2, without hard-coding that I want to take the SUM of D2:D11? I'm sure there's a simple solution for this, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Functions to use**

Let me show you this by using two functions. We will use:

```
=MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match type])
```

and

```
=OFFSET(reference, rows, columns, [height], [width])
```

**How to use them**

So I have set up a worksheet like yours to start:

[image]

I first want to find which column to use. In my case, I used my "assist" column. In that cell I put:

```
=MATCH(A3,D1:H1,0)
```

This simply retrieves the column index in relation to column D.

From there you can use the OFFSET function to move the selection so many rows / columns based on input. In our case we are only moving by so many columns so we will use the following:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(D2:D6,0,B2-2))
```

Notice that for OFFSET, the second parameter is 0 because we are not moving our selection by rows at all. The third parameter is B2-2 which references our assist column. The D2:D6 is the original selection to which the selection is shifted based on what is in the columns or rows parameter.

**Combining formulas**

All of this can be done in one function of course (in one big formula) to which would look like this:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(D2:D6,0,MATCH(A3,D1:H1,0)-2))
```

I always find it helpful to break down long formulas into chunks to help understand how they work though.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful! Based on your answer I came up with a shorter version:

`=SUM(OFFSET($D$2:$D$11, 0, A2 - 1))`

You helped me to realise that all I need to is offset the range using the number on the column, and that'll do the job for me :)

Comment: @Lou Yep there are shorter ways to do the same thing. I laid it out the long way for better explanation. If it answered your question feel free to accept it as your answer and I am glad to be able to help :)